# Plotly Dash on R - How to change title character font

Tags: r, plotly-dash, plotly-dashr

I'm creating a dash app with R.

I'm working on something quite like this example : https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-phylogeny/
(source code : https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/tree/master/apps/dashr-phylogeny)

I would like to change the font character of the global title to use something else than Times New Roman.

I know that it is possible as I saw another character font on this example : https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-oil-and-gas/
(source code : https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/tree/master/apps/dashr-oil-and-gas)

But I haven't found on the source code which parameter to change.

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do :

I had to add this parameter for the title :

*Before :*

```
htmlH1("My title",id = "title")
```

*After :*

```
htmlH1("My title",id = "title",style=list("font-family"= "verdana"))
```

To solve this kind of issues, we have to look for the right CSS styles.